# How to find out weights of attributes in K-nearest neighbors algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have such code in python with dataset of [house prices](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

boston = load_boston()
y = boston.target
X = scale(boston.data)
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5, weights='distance', metric='minkowski', p=1)
knn.fit(X, y)
```

And now I can predict target attribute, in this case it's price:

```
knn.predict([-0.41771335,  0.28482986, -1.2879095 , ..., -1.45900038,
     0.44105193, -1.0755623 ])
```

As I understand [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) should find weights for each attribute to make a distance function.
Where can I find computed weights of each attribute? I wonder what attribute has strongest correlation with house price.

Comment: Why not simply determine the importance of a feature by directly computing correlation or mutual information with the target?

Comment: I've just started to study ML and don't know how to do it. I thought this algorithm will solve this problem.

Comment: simply compute np.correlate() between each feature and the labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually specify the weights via the metric argument.

First off, your question details are slightly incorrect. The algorithm doesn't *find* a distance function - you supply it with a metric in which to compute distances, and a function to compute weights as a function of those distances. You are using the default distance metric which, according to [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html) is just the good old Euclidean distance.

Weights are computed as the inverse of distance (also written in the docs), so you can manually find the k neighbors of a given point and compute their weights using the build in kneighbors method to find neighbors:

```
test = [[np.random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in xrange(len(X[0]))]]

neighbors, distances = knn.kneighbors(test)
for d in distances:
    weight = 1.0/d
    print weight
```

The problem is that all features enter into the calculation of *d* with equal weight because you've specified a Euclidean metric, i.e. d is the square root of

1*(x1_neighbor - x1_test)^2 + 1*(x2_neighbor - x2_test)^2 + ...

This is because the Minkowsky metric is just a matrix with ones along the diagonal. If you want different weights, you can specify an alternate metric. However, if you just want a quick and dirty way of telling how important the various features are, a typical way of estimating the importance of feature *i* is to randomly permute all values of feature *i* and see how much it hurts the performance of the regressor. You can read more about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#Variable_importance).

Comment: This algorithm gives weights to the points according for the distances between original and targets points, not for the attributes of the points, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, the code snippet prints the weights of the neighbors of the test point (sorry if that was unclear). By default, the features are weighted equally when finding the distance (because the Minkowsky metric just has ones along the diagonal).
I like the permutation test because it's intuitive and works with any regressor/classifier (a feature is important if replacing it with noise hurts the regressor a lot). I see that a commenter suggests looking at correlations, which I think is also a good approach here (can't think of a counter example right now, which isn't to say that none exist)